# SQL Server Error: String or binary would be truncated. (System.Data)

Tags: sql-server, csv, import, ssms, truncation

I'm trying to import CSV file into SQL Server via [Tasks]>>[Import Flat File].

I get the error

> The given value of type string from the data source cannot be converted to type nvarchar of the specified target column. (System.Data). String or binary would be truncated. (System.Data)

Now I get this error from time to time and I think it's usually associated with large column widths. And normally if it's a small file with small amount of columns I can usually identify the offending column/row.

But for large files with many columns and thousands of rows it is practically impossible. The error inconveniently doesn't tell you what column is affected.

From a best practice point of view is there a way to actually get around this vague error message to pinpoint which is the offending column/row?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: do you have unicode checked?

Comment: @Doug Coats. There doesn't seem to be anywhere in the [import flat file] process where you are prompted to check for Unicode

Comment: I edited your question to post an image. I didnt want to post as answer though. Feel free to delete if it doesnt apply.

Comment: @ Doug Coats. Ah ok. I never reach that stage. This error comes before that

Comment: Thats the very first screen though? That is the screen that is the default landing once you select flat file?

Comment: @DougCoats  You have not used the same wizard as the OP, which is why the options are different.  It appears as though you have used `Import Data`, whereas the OP is using `Import Flat File`.

Comment: Well that would make sesne lol

Comment: @Shaye  I would recommend that you use the `Import Data` wizard rather than the `Import Flat File` one, as it is more customisable.  Regarding your large data columns though, that is just good old source data validation.  If you're getting your data from a known system find out what the maximums are and use those in your staging area.  If not, you will need to have a staging area that can accomodate wide columns and then curate the data as you transform it.

Comment: I have also removed the edited in image as this should have been added in as a comment.  For reference, this is the link Doug added: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iu3jk.png

Comment: Thanks Doug Coats and iamdave. Yes I was using [import flat file] rather than [import data]. It definitely gives better control

Answer (score 0):

In task wizard, the data type for strings is chosen nvarchar(50) by default. If you haven't changed the length in the brackets and getting this error, then it means that one or more of your columns have at least one row with value length greater than 50. Calculate the maximum length for all your columns and change the length in brackets for each attributes accordingly.

Performance tip: reducing the variable length where you can will help with your DB performance in the long run.